# I am unable to install Jinja in Pycharm using pip3 install Jinja. How to solve this error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, jinja2

$ pip3 install Jinja
Collecting Jinja
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/50/70f41c599cf0ace6c554b07108916513c70d0e950b0abb18c27a865df7a2/Jinja-1.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-build-zmxr6gb7/Jinja/setup.py", line 28
        except DistutilsError, e:
                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zmxr6gb7/Jinja/

Comment: Hi Arjun. It would help for some reading the question to have some more information. For example which version of  Pycharm it is, the version of python.

Answer (score 2):

`Jinja` is old and supports only Python 2.

I guess you want to install `Jinja2`.

Comment: Yes but as I have seached on google and stackoverflow, I found that Jinja2 does not support in Pycharm Community version, It support only in Pycharm Pro. As I am new in programming and recently start learining Python and django so I want to know that is there any other free platform/software like pycharm for learning Django.

Comment: We do no recommend IDEs or other tools dues to our community guidelines here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: LMGTFY - a Web search for "python ide" gives *many* alternatives.